# WPF spline curve chart by templating lineseries

Tags: wpf, charts, spline

I have an requirement in my application to create spline chart instead lineseries chart. I know WPF doesn't provide splineseries directly.

How I can customize (template) lineseries chart to display curve graph, I don't want to use any third part paid tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you mean by spline series is smoothed line series, you can use [OxyPlot](http://www.oxyplot.org/) (which is of course free). Use a `LineSeries` and set `Smooth` property to be `true`:

here an example:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "OxyPlot" };
        plotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis { Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom });
        plotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis { Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });
        var series1 = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries
        {
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 5,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White
        };
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 6));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 4));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 7));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6, 6));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8, 8));
        series1.Smooth = true;
        plotModel.Series.Add(series1);
        this.Content = new OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView() { Model = plotModel };
    }
```

Note this part: `series1.Smooth = true;`

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. Thanks it is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is outdated.

At the time of writing, The property `InterpolationAlgorithm` is used to set the spline type.

```
var series = new LineSeries
{
    InterpolationAlgorithm = InterpolationAlgorithms.CanonicalSpline
};
```